# Need help understanding DTD schema

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm quite new to XML, can someone tell me what exactly this code is supposed to do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859"?> 
<!DOCTYPE person [ 
    <!ELEMENT first_name(#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT last_name(#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT PROFESSION(#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT name(first_name, last_name)>
    <!ELEMENT person (name, profession)>]> 
<person>
    <name>
        <last_name>Jack</last_name>
        <last_name>Jill</last_name> 
    </name>
</person>
```

Comment: Please edit your title to be a bit more concise about what you're asking here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an embedded DTD, which dictates which elements are permitted in which order, e.g. the "name" element must contain first_name followed by last_name.

It's an unconventional approach, but should be valid. Normally the DTD is an external file, rather than being embedded in the source document.

Comment: hi and thanks again, it is me again. please what should be the changes to be made for the code to run without error.thanks

Comment: You don't "run" an XML document. You haven't told us what your problem is, either.

Comment: thanks for replying. can we say the code above is well-formed and why? thanks for replying.

Answer (score 8):

That is an XML file, and it doesn't do anything by itself. Instead, it appears to define a "person" with two last names (but the file is invalid because the DTD indicates both first name and last name).

Answer (score 1):

The xml document first indicates that it's an xml document by having a prolog ( `<?xml` ). An optional DOCTYPE is defined, this basically just is a list of all possible elements and attributes in the document, and lastly the actual document itself is defined with `person` being the root node, `name` being the first child, having two children which are `last_name` nodes.

I think the first node under `name` should be `first_name`, not `last_name`.